# Does the reflectivity of metal change when placed in a strong electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electric-fields, reflection, metals

I've read that most metal surfaces are reflective because their electrons are free enough to move with the fluctuating electric fields of visible light. Would holding these electrons to one side (or back from the surface) with an electric field change the metal's reflectivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a normal electric field to a metal produces a very thin surface charge (accumulation or depletion of electrons) which prevents the further penetration of the field into the interior. For example, copper has a free electron density of $8.5·10^{22} cm^{-3}$. Maximum applicable electric fields $E$ to a metal surface are on the order of $10^7 V/cm$ (onset of electron field emission), for this the width $d$ of a surface depletion/accumulation zone would be $d≈\epsilon _0 E/(q n)≈ 6.5·10^{-11} cm$, which is much smaller than the wavelength of light $\lambda≈5·10^{-4} cm$ . Therefore, the change in surface dielectric constant and conductance produced by the field in an extremely thin region is minuscule as compared to the effect of the unchanged free bulk electrons. Therefore, in a metal, an electric field effect on light reflection/transmission is, in principle possible but the effect is extremely small.

Comment: Thank you. Very informative. If you don't mind...What would happen if I had a metal nanorod sitting in an electric field along its axis? If I shine light that's polarized along the axis of the rod wouldn't the electrons in the rod have to oppose the pull of the applied field for half of the cycle in order to reflect the light?

Comment: @james - The electrons would be oscillating due to the electric field force creating an oscillation current. The nanorods can work like little (dipole) antennas. This has been used to convert light energy into electric DC power when the oscillation current is rectified with a diode. See Optical rectennas  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rectenna.

Comment: @ freecharly thanks. I kinda forgot that the electrons were in equilibrium when in the electric field. For some reason I thought they would only move when the light's electric field was aligned with the artificial electric field. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Google on [electron metal shiny](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=electron+metal+shiny) and you find things like this: _""Metals look metallic because they contain a ‘fluid’ composed of movable electrons. This electrical ‘fluid’ is an excellent reflector of light waves, and it causes the surfaces of metals to act like mirrors."_